# Trying to get property of non-object Error - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm developing a blog in laravel and I'm having trouble with foreign keys between two tables: `posts` and `categories`.

I created two models: `Post` (for the posts table) and `Category` (for the categories table). In my view I wrote this code : `<p>Posted In: {{$post->category->id}}</p>`, but this error is showing :

> **ErrorException:** Trying to get property of non-object foreign key error

Post Model :

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function category()
     {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

---

Category Model :

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public $table = 'categories';  

    public function posts() 
    { 
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
}
```

---

View form :

```
@extends('main')

@section('title', "| $post->title " )

@section('content')

    <div class="row">
        <div class ="col-md-8></col-md-8 col-md-offset-2"> 
            <h1>{{$post->title}}</h1>
            <p>{{$post->body}}</p>
            <hr>
            <p>Posted In:{{$post->category->id}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

I expect that the code : `<p>Posted In: {{$post->category->id}}</p>` 
will  output the category in the blog post.

Comment: Please share your DB migration.

Comment: have you tried to `dd($post->category()->first());`?

Comment: Show us your controller, please.

Comment: show your code how you fetch the data.

Comment: Can you confirm that the post definitely has a `category_id` value and there is also a a row in the `categories` table that has an `id` that matches the `category_id`?

Comment: yes i can confirm that the post has a category_id value and there is also  a row in the categories table that has an id that matches the category_id

Answer (score 5):

### TL;DR

I'm pretty sure this has to be related with the new default in Laravel 5.8 in which the primary key has changed from `Integer` to `BigInteger`.

If so, change your foreign keys column type from:

```php
$table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
```

to:

```php
$table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
// or:          ^^^
$table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned();
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

### Explanation

**In previous versions** of Laravel (`5.7` or lower) this was the default behavior:

```php
Schema::create('categories', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id'); // <-- so, an 'integer'
    // ...
});
```

So then in your other tables you just do this:

```php
Schema::create('posts', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('category_id'); // <-- to match, also an integer
    // or this: $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
    // ...
});
```

**But now** in Laravel `5.8+` the default migration looks like:

```php
Schema::create('categories', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id'); // <----- so now is a BigInteger
    // ...
});
```

Which is a `BigInteger`. So in your foreign keys you should use this type instead:

```php
Schema::create('posts', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id'); // <---- to match, use this
    // or this: $table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned();
    // ...
});
```

Check this article of Povilas Korop: [Be Careful: Laravel 5.8 Added bigIncrements As Defaults](https://laraveldaily.com/be-careful-laravel-5-8-added-bigincrements-as-defaults/)

Answer (score 0):

As per the error, it looks like eloquent is having a hard time to find the relation with the mismatch foreign key.
By default, it looks `posts` table to have a foreign key as `category_id`. If you have something else, you have to define in relation function. btw, could you show how you have been fetching posts with the category?